# Prove or disprove the pointwise convergence of Fourier Series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

Let $\alpha >1$ and function $f$ defined as

\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
(\text{log}\frac{1}{|\text{sin}(x)|})^{-\alpha} & \textrm{$x\neq k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
0 & \textrm{$x=k\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$}\\
\end{array} \right.
\end{equation*}

Prove (or disprove) that the Fourier series of $f$:
\begin{equation*}
s_N(f;x)=\sum_{n=-N}^N \hat{f_n}e^{inx}
\end{equation*}
converges to $f$ pointwisely.

Note that the function $f$ goes to $\infty$ when $x=\frac{k\pi}{2}$ for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ is differentiable except those points. Can one just apply the theorem that $f\in C^1$ then $S_N(f;x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$? Also it is noticeable that $f$ is not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Note $\log$ looks better than $log$; same with $\sin.$

Comment: It looks to me like $f(x) \approx [1/(x-\pi/2)^2]^\alpha$ near $\pi/2.$ So $f$ isn't even in $L^1.$ How does the Fourier series even make sense?